# Silverlight: Webservice method returning ObservableCollection instead of Generic List

Tags: silverlight, web-services

I have a webservice that calls a method that returns a generic list of class `BodyPartUrls` like so:

```
public List<BodyPartUrls> getCharacterClassBody(int characterClassID)
{
    var bpulst = new List<BodyPartUrls>();
    var iqcb = ydc.ClassBodies.Where(cb =>  cb.characterClassID == characterClassID);

    foreach (var icb in iqcb)
    {
        var bpu = new BodyPartUrls();
        bpu.bodyPartName = icb.BodyPart.bodyPartName;
        bpu.bodyName = icb.Body.bodyName;
        bpu.puppetID = characterClassID;
        bpulst.Add(bpu);
    }
    return bpulst;
}
```

BodyPartUrls only consists of string and integer properties, note that ydc is refering to a datacontext. This the code in the webservice :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<BodyPartUrls> getCharacterClassBody(int characterClassID)
    {
       return b.getCharacterClassBody(characterClassID);
    }
```

Now to call the method in silverlight I utalised the following code :

```
public void initialiseBodiesSoapClientClient()
{
    string webServiceUrl = pu.GetUrlForResource("Bodies.asmx");
    System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
    EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(webServiceUrl);
    bsc = new BodiesRef.BodiesSoapClient(binding, endpoint);
    bsc.getCharacterClassBodyCompleted += new EventHandler<Yambushi.BodiesRef.getCharacterClassBodyCompletedEventArgs>(bsc_getCharacterClassBodyCompleted);
}
```

The method `pu.GetUrlForResource` get's the url of where the webservice is hosted, the following is method `bsc_getCharacterClassBodyCompleted` :

```
void bsc_getCharacterClassBodyCompleted(object sender, Yambushi.BodiesRef.getCharacterClassBodyCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   bpulist = e.Result;
}
```

`bpulist` is a generic list of BodyPartUrls, for some reason `e.Result` is returning ObservableCollection instead of the generic list. I have similar code to retreive other generic lists that work fine so I really can't understand why this is acting differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click Configure Service Reference. Under the Data Type section you can select what type you want collections or dictionaries to return as.